# Twitter bootstrap 100% footer background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My site has fixed width layout. I mean i'm not using responsive layout.

So I removed bootstrap-responsive.css file.

But it looks like bootstrap has some bug in the footer background while using fixed width layout.

I mean check this snapshot.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix that issue?

Comment: It's not easy to find the exact issue from this picture so could you please share your html and css so that we can find it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the scrollbar at the bottom, it seems that your window size is less than the page size, since you removed the responsiveness. Based on a quick test on the Bootstrap doc, I think that you can fix this by adding `width:100%;` to the body tag. Everything is just set to fill the item containing it and nothing else has a width set (even the body tag by default). This should stretch the page to wrap around all elements instead of just filling the window.

UPDATE: CSS should be `min-width:960px`. Naturally, in other instances you would want to change this minimum width value, but for the Bootstrap CSS without responsiveness, this is the base grid system width.

Comment: Scratch that, add `min-width: 960px` to the body declaration at line 13 in `docs.css`. That should keep the body wrapped around all the elements even when you aren't using responsiveness. (With the idea being that without the responsiveness, your minimum page width IS 960px.) Updating answer...